# How to map Traffic Count Points to Streets?

Tags: qgis, cartography, streets

I've got point data representing traffic count locations and I am trying to figure out the best way to represent them on a map.I thought about kriging to provide a continuous surface but I don't think that is a good option.

I could do a spatial join to join the points to the streets but I'm not sure how I could represent the actual counts. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the objective of your analysis. I deal a lot with traffic data and representation. Furthermore, can you provide a few images perhaps from other resource online of what you're trying to do or replicate and I can perhaps guide you in the right direction

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the others, more information!
You could symbolize the points using graduated symbols which would symbolize the points according to the count eg. (small count for one road would be a small circle).

Answer (score 1):

You could join to your streets layer and adjust the symbology of the streets layer to reflect the count?  Either adjust the size of the lines based on the count field or possibly the color.  It might be helpful for us to know what the map is supposed to convey.